# Generate GUID in each repositories create method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Say I have a bunch of repositories:

```
CustomerRepository();
SalesRepositor();
EmployeeRepository();
etc
```

Say each one of these has a create method e.g.CustomerRepository could be:

```
public void Add(Customer entity)
{
    _dbContext.Set<Customer>().Add(entity);
}
```

Say I wanted to use a GUID for all of the entity IDs.  Where would I put the following logic:

```
entity.id = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Would I put this in every repositories create method or is there a "better" place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the Repository is not the best place for guid creation; with that said, I could think of many more severe sins if you have a compelling reason to do so.

The repository's job is simply to abstract away the data layer. Unrelated to your question, your repositories are failing to do so, which may be why you have come to this question in the first place.

To be frank, the repositories you are using are useless code bloat at the moment. They do nothing but add unnecessary complexity. You EF classes represent the data in your DB, so using them directly in code makes your application tightly bound to the DB.

Your repository's job is to map those entities to a business object which your created yourself. If you deem this task unnecessary for your project (hopefully, because it is a simple CRUD app), then you should not over-complicate it by defining repositories. If you think about it, DBContext is already a repository.

Back to your question, the point of creating a key in code instead of the DB is to allow your application to make its own key unencumbered by the complexities data access; therefore, doing so in the repository is rather counterproductive, as a repository's entire job is data access.

Furthermore, a warning, GUIDs are notoriously slow for clustered indexes. There is no rule that says you may only have one unique key. Perhaps, consider a GUID for your application logic key, and an identity integer defined by your database.

In summary, having your repository create your GUID is not great, but it is far from the most troublesome thing in the above code. A better place would be in a builder, factory, or whatever code first initialized the new object.

Here is an example of a more useful repository:

```
class CustomerRepository
{
     public BusinessModel.Customer GetCustomer(Guid customerId)
     {
         Customer entity = _dbContext.Customers.Where(c => x.id == id).Single();
         return new BusinessModel.Customer
         {
             Id = entity.Id,
             Name = entity.Name
             // TODO: More properties
         }
     }

     // TODO: Create, update, delete, ect methods
}
```

Comment: Why are the repositories "failing to do so"?

Comment: @w0051977 an Entity Framework entity represents a row of database table (see active record pattern), your repository has public references to this entity, therefore the rest of your app can see your database structure. But the whole point of a repository is to abstract away, therefore it is failing to do its job.

Comment: @w0051977 Let's say, you had to split up a database table for performance reasons, if the repository did its job correctly, only the repository would know... it would look like this... `Customer GetCustomer(id) { return  _dbContext.Get<ActiveCustomer>(id) ?? _dbContext.Get<InactiveCustomer>(id); }`

Comment: Are you saying that the repository is poor because it has a public modifier?

Comment: @w0051977 no, it is poor because it is repetitive and exposes database details.

Comment: can you provide a "better" example or a hyperlink?

Comment: @w0051977 edited answer to include an example

Comment: I was reading that generated entity framework classes are not POCO i.e. they inherit from EntityObject.  However, this does not appear to be the case when I use DatabaseFirst.  Is this true or was it true only for an earlier version of Entity Framework?

Comment: Entity Object was superceded by dbContext.  I see that now.

Comment: @w0051977 I am not up to speed with the latest EF. I don't use it, because imo, it is a very bad technology. It is slow, and confuses developers with its terminology. Last time I used it (EF4) there was an optional plugin that let you use POCOs instead. This however, while better, still does not solve the issue that they are directly mapped to the DB.

Comment: Thanks.  What do you use? NHibernate?

Comment: @w0051977 StackExchange Dapper.net (what this site uses behind the scenes)